# How to get pointer to outcoming buffer using asm?

Tags: c, x86, nasm, cdecl

I have to write function in asm, and i have prototype in C

```
void fdct(float *in, float *out, unsigned int n);
```

Where:

- `in`: pointer to incoming data buffer
- `out`: pointer to outcoming data buffer
- `n`: amount of data matrices.

Function doesn't return anything, but works with array of outcoming data and must change it according to result.

As I understand, in cdecl stack will look like:

```
esp: ret
esp+4: *in - address
esp+8: *out - address 
esp+12: value of n
```

I got, how to work in asm with incoming buffer, but I don't understand how to return new address of outcoming buffer - just putting new address into `esp+8` isn't resultive, it doesn't change value of `*out`. How can I manage this problem?

Comment: What operating system are you using? The `cdecl` calling convention is subtly different on *nix as compared to Windows.

Comment: Windows, i forgot to note this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not how this should work.

Your assembler function does **not** allocate a `float` (or an array of `float`) and *return* it in `out`.

Instead, the *caller* should allocate such an array (e.g. using `malloc()`, `calloc()` -- or whatever functions his or her language provides -- or simply as local variable on the stack) and *pass the address of the first element in* `out`. Your function just *fills* the array with suitable `float` values, probably up to `n` elements.

Example:

```
float a[16] = ... ;  /* fill it up with suitable values */
float b[16] = { 0 }; /* receives result values */

fdct(a, b, 16);
```

Comment: If you *did* want the function to allocate memory, you would need to change the `out` parameter to be a pointer-to-a-pointer. But I agree the design you propose is preferable, because it makes ownership easier to reason about.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help!